# Block remote access by Java

Tags: java, linux, remote-access, putty

I can connect to the Linux server i have using Putty(i have got IP, username and password). I have got java program in there, started by bat file. I would like to break existing connection and block future connections by putty, after starting the java program. Any idea if thats even possible?

Comment: Really bad idea, if needed, How do you connect after your java program is running ?

Comment: i will move my from a chair to the server and stop the program or restart Pc :)

Comment: Does running `service ssh stop` from the application work for you?

Comment: yeah, its working fine from a command line, any idea how to run it using just java?

Comment: Use ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec.

Answer (score 1):

You could edit your script to run the Java program with `nohup` to make sure the process keeps running after you log out and then kill the ssh daemon after it's been started ([man page for nohup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)).

I don't know of a way of doing this programatically in Java, at least not in a platform independent way.